# Comprehension problem regarding exercise in chapter on Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

I am retired and working my way through a Stewart Calculus book for personal interest.  I am having problems understanding part of an exercise at the end of the chapter on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  This is basic, introductory material so please bear with me.

The last exercise in this chapter has 4 parts (a, b, c and d).  I am having problems with part b.  I am hoping a reader here will help me understand what exactly is being requested as the solution.  The exercise states the following:

*A high-tech company purchases a new computing system whose initial value is $V$.  The system will depreciate at the rate $f=f(t)$ and will accumulate maintenance costs at the rate of $g=g(t)$, where $t$ is the time measured in months.  The company wants to determine the optimal time to replace the system.*

*Part b) Suppose that*

$$
f(t)= 
\begin{cases}
\frac{V}{15}-\frac{V}{450}t, & if \ 0 \lt t \le30 \\[2ex]
0, & if \ t>30
\end{cases}
$$

*and*

$$
g(t)=\frac{Vt^2}{12,900},\ t>0
$$

*Determine the length of time $T$ for the total depreciation $D(t)= \int_{0}^{t}f(s)ds$ to equal the initial value $V$.*

Here are my questions:

1. This part asks us to determine the total depreciation time $D(t)$.  I understand this is exclusive of the maintenance rate.  In other words, the depreciation rate $f(t)$ is factored into the solution BUT the maintenance rate $g(t)$ is not (i.e. I can ignore the maintenance rate).  Is this correct?  If this is not correct then can you please explain why?
2. Again, we are asked to determine the total depreciation time.  The formula for $f(t)$ shows the time interval of depreciation is $(0,30]$.  I understand this to mean the computer system has fully depreciated when $t=30$. So the total depreciation $D(t)=V$ is when $t=30$. Is this correct? If so then this seems to me to the answer to part $b$.  This however seems too simplistic an answer and therefore believe I have failed to comprehend exactly what is being asked, and what is required as a solution to part b.  Can someone help me understand where/what the mistake is that I am making?

Thank you,

Ian

Comment: What you're doing is using common sense. Why did they define $f(t)$ to be $0$ when $t>30$? It stands to reason that we must have $D(t)=V$ when $t=30$. But do the integral to reassure yourself that common sense should prevail.

Comment: Chuckle!   I used two different methods (i.e. computed the integral) and both came up with the same answer of 30.  Given I am functionally illiterate when it comes to math, I naturally assumed I was making a mistake.  I appreciate your quick response.  Thank you.

Comment: Enjoy your adventures. Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: Trying to provide answer.  First time I am using this math editor.  It is extremely slow to format and I am trying to figure out to use it.  For example, I can't add line indents and line breaks when using the "align equations" Mathjax syntax.   Will post an answer if I can figure this out.  I'm only familiar with the default equation editor in MSWord.

Comment: LOL, yes, there's a little bit of a learning curve.  I have been doing LaTeX for 35 years or so, so it's old hat to me. When you do \begin and \end{align*}, & does the alignment and \\ will give you line breaks. You can find tutorials, but make an approximation to it for starters.

Comment: I've already tried both your suggestions but I'm not getting what I expect.  Your suggestion to post my answer sent me back to MSWord and I just realized I can set it to use LaTeX.  So I will start experimenting with LaTex in MSWord because the formatting time in MSWord is so much faster than in this web page editor.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I admire your tenacity. If you get close, post it and let me know and I'll edit it for you.